# Layout two demos from material-ui documentation

Tags: css, reactjs, material-ui

I'm trying to combine two demos from material-ui documentation.

- [Clipped under the app bar](https://material-ui.com/components/drawers/#clipped-under-the-app-bar) - This is the page layout
- [Fixed header](https://material-ui.com/components/tables/#fixed-header) - This is a table with a fixed header.

I want the table to take all the available page height, but still have a fixed header.

The problem is that the "fixed-header" table on the right side, doesn't stick its header, there's a page scrollbar and the header scrolls up with the page. unless I'm adding a `maxHeight` to the table (Similar to the original "Fixed header" demo). BUT, with `maxHeight` I can't fit the table to the full page height...

Here's a [CodeSandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/material-demo-5zu03?fontsize=14) demonstrating the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To use this position: sticky property, the parent element must have a defined height.

In your case it is possible to define something as height: 100vh.

**See index.html**

https://codesandbox.io/s/material-demo-v44v6

**Demo working**

https://v44v6.csb.app/

```
<style>

       .makeStyles-tableWrapper-130{
          height: calc(100vh - 84px);
        }
        .makeStyles-content-5{
          padding: 24px 24px 0;
          flex-grow: 1;
          height: auto;
          box-sizing: border-box;
        }

</style>
```

Comment: It's a good and working solution, but the `84px` and the `100vh` are too hard-coded.
If there's no better solution I will surly accept this one.

Comment: 100vh is dynamic, it corresponds to the height of the window. 84px is the height of the header + margin-bottom so it doesn't stick together

Comment: There's no way to "let" the parent "decide" the height?

Answer (score 0):

Don't use hard pixel value you can use viewport height

```js
const useStyles = makeStyles({
  tableWrapper: {
    height: "100vh",
    overflow: "auto"
  }
});
```

Demo Here: https://0qy7e.csb.app/